# Favicon change does not work (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, cache, favicons

Magento 2 shows me this path to the favicon in the source:

> /pub/static/frontend/xx/MinimalBlack/de_CH/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico

I delete this file and ad my own favicon to my theme here:

> /app/design/frontend/xx/MinimalBlack/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico

But it creates me always the Magento favicon in the static folder, not my favicon. What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using magento 2.0.2 then go to

**`Stores > Configuration > General > Design`**.

You can change your favicon by upload it.

Answer (score 3):

As Omitri wrote before, the favicon you want to use must be placed in:

```
/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Theme/web/favicon.ico
```

There are couple more steps you need to perform to see it live, though:

1. Clear the cache of your browser
2. Clear `pub/static` and `var` directories without removing `.htaccess` files

Here's a [link to docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/favicon.html#add-custom-favicons-manually).

Comment: If you use Adobe Commerce, the favicon should be placed in `/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Enterprise/web/favicon.ico`.

Answer (score 0):

The file location should be:
/app/design/frontend/xx/MinimalBlack/Magento_Theme/web/favicon.ico

Comment: This did not work for me.